# Facebook share dialog

Tags: iphone, ios7

I got one problem in Facebook web-dialog which i am implementing in iPhone(ios7). After Facebook login whenever i click on share button it is not opening a Facebook web dialog. But after closing the application if i run again my application and click share button it is working perfectly. I don't know what is the problem. Please help me.

This is my share function

```
[FBWebDialogs presentFeedDialogModallyWithSession:nil
                                       parameters:params
                                          handler:
 ^(FBWebDialogResult result, NSURL *resultURL, NSError *error)

 {
     if (error) {
         // Error launching the dialog or sending the request.
         NSLog(@"Error sending request.");
     } else {
         if (result == FBWebDialogResultDialogNotCompleted) {
             // User clicked the "x" icon
             NSLog(@"User canceled request.");
         } else {
             // Handle the send request callback
             NSDictionary *urlParams = [self parseURLParams:[resultURL query]];
             if (![urlParams valueForKey:@"request"]) {
                 // User clicked the Cancel button
                 NSLog(@"User canceled request.");
             } else {
                 // User clicked the Send button
                 NSString *requestID = [urlParams valueForKey:@"request"];
                 NSLog(@"Request ID: %@", requestID);
             }
         }
     }
 }];
```

Comment: Did you get anything on console? Problem might be related with the session which is being passed as nil!

Comment: Yes,Session is not passing.

Comment: can you please tell how to pass and retrieve session.

Comment: Just a pointer, try testing on the actual device and not the simulator. I personally get different issues with facebook when using simulator.

Comment: Hey i got the problem,actually i am using tabbarcontroller which i am creating programatically in app delegate.Whenever i go to tab bar controller first time it will not work.but if i am using simple view controller Facebook share dialog perfectly working.please help me.